# CArrayDataProvider in YII sorting not working on some fields

Tags: php, sorting, yii

I have created Dataprovider in controller and pass it to view file. It display correct Data. There are total 7 columns to display.
But only on 2 fields sorting is not working and throwing ERROR-500.

In controller File, my Code is :

```
    $OutboundRatecardDetails_data = OutboundRatecardDetails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('orc_id'=>$orc_id));

    $pageSize = 10;
    if(isset($_GET['pageSize']))
    {
        $pageSize = $_GET['pageSize'];
        Yii::app()->user->setState('pageSize', (int)$_GET['pageSize']);
        unset($_GET['pageSize']);
    }

    $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($OutboundRatecardDetails_data, array(
        'id'=>'orcd_id',
        'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
            'orcd_id', 'des_id', 'orcd_duration','orcd_rate','orcd_grace_duration','orcd_description'
        ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>$pageSize,
        ),
        'keyField'=>'orcd_id',
    ));

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
```

In admin.php view file, my code is :

```
    <?php  $this->widget('application.components.widgets.tlbExcelView', array(
        'id'=>'Outbound-rate-card-details-grid',
        'dataProvider'  =>$dataProvider,
        'itemsCssClass' =>'table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed',
        'pagerCssClass' =>'dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pagination',
        'htmlOptions'   =>array('class'=>'adv-table'),        
        'columns'=>array(
            'des_id'=>array(
            'name'=>'des_id',
            'header'=>'Destination',                
            'value' => '(!empty($data->rel_destination->des_prefix) ? $data->rel_destination->des_prefix : "")',
            ),

            array(
            'name'=>'orcd_grace_duration',
            'header'=>'Grace Duration',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'max-width:150px; white-space:normal;word-break:break-all;'),
            ),

            array(
            'name'=>'orcd_duration',
            'header'=>'Incr. Duration',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'max-width:150px; white-space:normal;word-break:break-all;'),
            ),

            array(
            'name'=>'orcd_rate',
            'header'=>'Incr. Rate',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'max-width:150px; white-space:normal;word-break:break-all;'),
            ),

            array(
            'name'=>'orcd_min_duration',
            'header'=>'Min. Duration',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'max-width:150px; white-space:normal;word-break:break-all;'),
            ),

            array(
            'name'=>'orcd_min_rate',
            'header'=>'Min. Rate',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'max-width:150px; white-space:normal;word-break:break-all;'),
            ),

            array(
            'name'=>'orcd_description',
            'header'=>'Rate Description',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'max-width:150px; white-space:normal;word-break:break-all;'),
            ),
        ),
    )); ?>
```

When I try to sort on 2nd and 3rd field (orcd_grace_duration,orcd_duration), it throws error. Error screenshot is also attached. Other than these 2 fields, sorting is perfectly working.

[image]

Comment: check php log files for exact error. Error 500 means Internal Server Error. Seems like some parse or db error.

Comment: in error Log, it gives : PHP Fatal error:  Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in /framework/web/CArrayDataProvider.php on line 151

Comment: Okay. I am not sure if [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2082) is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs when CArrayDataProvider's columns having same values.
Try using CActiveDataPrider instead.

You just need to change code in your controller like below:

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('orc_id',$orc_id,true);

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('OutboundRatecardDetails', array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'         =>  array(
                'defaultOrder' =>  'orc_id desc',
            ),
            'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>$pageSize,
        ),
    ));
```